# Using Massive Amounts of Implemented Interfaces

Tags: java

I am trying to create a game involving machines and items. I have a simple item interface and every item will implement this.

I would usually just create a class for every item, but there could potentially be thousands of items, and it doesn't feel right to create thousands of files for all the items. This applies to other large amounts of types of objects I might have. (ground tiles, entities)

I need a type safe way to store all these implemented interfaces. I need to easily be able to create a new item in my code, with only the name of the item.

I was thinking of having a huge class with subclasses holding lots of final constants that would all be anonymous classes, but this also seems like a bad way of doing this.

Is there any good way to do what I have in mind? (Sorry that this is a little vague)

My item interface is currently,

```
package com.bobona.craftable.model;

import com.bobona.craftable.CraftableGame;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public interface Item {

    String getId();
    Map<String, Integer> getValues();
    void onUse(AtomicReference<CraftableGame> game, Long entityUsedByIndex);
    void onSecondaryUse(AtomicReference<CraftableGame> game, Long 
    entityUsedByIndex);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use an attribute that indicates the type of the item?

Comment: I need to be able to reference something like GameUtil.Item.METAL and get a new instance of an anonymous class implementing my item interface.

Comment: OK, how many abstract methods does your interface have?

Comment: So, you couldn't abstract the concepts in such away to provide "base" or "core" implementations which rely mostly on input to configure themselves (ie, a `Title` would have an image and possible a position and transformation applied it, but could, through implementing speciality interfaces, act as a "ground" title or a "sky" title or what ever)

Comment: Items will have a very wide range of uses, so a core item would have to simply be an item that only is used in recipes and serves no other purpose :/

Comment: It also wouldn't be nice to use non type-safe values to define items in recipes, as that would quickly become a pain to debug and refactor.

Comment: You can try a more hierarchical approach. Have a base `Item` Then a sub class `Tile` and a sub class `RecipeItem` etc. That should be able to cut down on redundancies. Then if you have a bunch of `RecipeItem`s that have no other purpose either instantiate them all as instances of the same class or do the anonymous class at that level.

Comment: twain249, that seems like a good way of doing it... I don't have any way of up voting that comment or marking it as a good answer...

Comment: In school, yes we create a new class for a new unique item. But in making games, we don't do that. Just create a generic class for item creation. Store all your items in the **Data File**. Not in not classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a difficult design problem, and there is no one size fits all answer as far as I know. As mentioned by Makoto in another answer, much of your approach will be dictated by the actual details of your specific game.

> I would usually just create a class for every item, but there could potentially be thousands of items, and it doesn't feel right to create thousands of files for all the items.

I completely agree with this statement.

> I need a type safe way to store all these implemented interfaces.

I'm not sure that this is possible (literally as written), if we accept the previous statement that separate classes or interfaces aren't the correct approach. However, if instead of type safe you'll settle for *verifiable at runtime by some yet-unspecified mechanism*, then I think it's quite doable.

> [From Comment] It also wouldn't be nice to use non type-safe values to define items in recipes, as that would quickly become a pain to debug and refactor.

I agree you'll want some sort of verification, but as previously mentioned full-blown compile-time type safety might not be feasible while also avoiding thousands of separate classes. I think the key here is to reliably detect errors, respond to them in a way that doesn't break the game, and generate sensible debug messages for the developer.

---

There are a lot of ways to go about accomplishing this; which one you choose is going to depend on your exact requirements, your preferences, and a number of implementation details that I have no way of knowing. Some things that I think you should look into or consider:

- Inheritance probably won't work at all, for the reasons you've already identified.
- Composition or the [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) might improve things initially, but [probably won't scale the way you want](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/27054).
- You could go for a RDBMS approach, as [outlined here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/5837).
- You might try a JSON based approach or equivalent, as [outlined here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/108566).
- The [component pattern](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html) fits my understanding of your problem very well.
- [This](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/31491) is an incredibly well written answer detailing how to implement the component pattern for entities (which I think include the types of items you were describing) using bit fields.
- [This](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/4516) is a very similar question to yours on the gamedev stackexchange with some good answers.

Personally I like the component pattern, and am a fan of using JSON or an equivalent language for specifying the items themselves. Hopefully at least some of the above information will help you as you iteratively modify your architecture to meet your gameplay requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to need to think about the hierarchy of your game ***first*** before you start coding anything.

---

You haven't described anything about this game, like what's in it or what the objects are or what things can interface with what, so I'll describe a popular game I like - Factorio.

In this game, amongst *other* things, there are a few things to describe:

- Items which allow you to craft other items
- Belts which move items
- Assemblers which turn items into other items

So I would start with describing the basic hierarchy of how these things interact.

- A class for items, and an enum to allow us to describe what the item is and how we can interact with it (if it's craftable or not, which are rules owned by the assemblers)
- A class for belts, with as many belt types as we want to support (right now the game has 3)
- A class for assemblers, which describe how many items can be accepted at once as well as how fast they craft things

You'll have to understand how your items interact with the environment before you describe rules.  For example:

- Items can be placed on belts through the use of an inserter.
- Items can be placed into an assembler through the use of an inserter.

This will require more thought on your part.  But, the number of classes you should have would be small provided that there are only a handful of elements in the world.

Answer (score 2):

> would usually just create a class for every item, but there could potentially be thousands of items, and it doesn't feel right to create thousands of files for all the items.

Yes, you should not be doing that. Classes act as blueprint of your object. We don't create a new class for every new object. If you see that all your items share a common attribute (e.g. `name`), then those can be used as the attribute of your base class:

```
public abstract class Entity{
    protected String name;
    public Entity(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then for those object which is an Item, you can extends it to base class:

```
//example
public abstract class Monster extends Entity{
    protected int damage;
    //constructor not shown
}
```

If you also need to indicate whether an Entity is `Ground` or `Air`. You can also use Interface as such:

```
public Interface OnAir{
}

public Interface OnGround{
}
```

Then you can have:

```
//example
public class FlyingMonster extends Monster implements OnAir {
    //your other attributes here
}
public class LandMonster extends Monster implements OnGround {
    //your other attributes here
}
```

Now you have the flexibility to manipulate the type of object you want.

To store all your monsters (ground and air):

```
ArrayList<Monster> monsters = new ArrayList<>();
```

To store all entities including monsters:

```
ArrayList<Entity> entities= new ArrayList<>();
```

---

The above solution is to reply your question. However, I should mention that in game making, I wouldn't want to create that many classes. But instead I would store all my entities in a datafile. If there are special attributes for your entity. For example, a fire-based weapon which does 30% extra damage to all ice-based creture. I would not code this in Java as well. But instead store it in a script file. That fire-based weapon will then be referenced to the script file.

The same logic applies to your Non-Playable Characters.

So what is the benefit of storing them in scripts and datafiles? You can add / remove / edit your entities without the need to recompile your codes. You can change how the weapons work, how your character behaves, how your NPCs talk  without changing anything in Java.

This means that you can now add new items into the game by just typing into the textfile.

Comment: I respect the idea of storing metadata and values in a data file, but you would still want *some* kind of structure for your application.  Further, I simply disagree with the idea that you need an interface for `OnAir` and `OnGround`; that seems...useless to me.

Comment: @Makoto There are many possibilities which ultimately depends on how the game is eventually implemented. I am giving him an idea of using marker interface to indicate the type of a particular object if he needs to. And, yes he still need some basic structures / classes which I also mentioned.

Comment: No really, a marker interface is something you use when you don't have a better solution.  The idea of a marker interface breaks a lot of things since there's no formal contract to implement anymore. You're imposing a fake API to satisfy OO, which is a smell.

Comment: @Makoto Hmm well, you can amend my solution about the code smell if there are indeed issues with the interfaces. In fact, If I were to implement a game with Java, I probably won't be using Interface at all (or use sparingly). Most of the things will be stored in datafiles and scripts (including the hierarchies of the entities).